# Scroll Element in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have this input element:

```
<input type="text" class="text field" value="" id="subject" name="subject">
```

for button submit:

```
<input type="submit" class="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Ok, Done.">
```

Then I have some other elements, like other text inputs, textareas, etc.

When the user clicks on that input with #subject, the page should scroll to the last element of the page with a nice animation. It should be a scroll to bottom and not to top.

The last item of the page is a submit button with #submit:

The animation should not be too fast and should be fluid.

I am running the latest jQuery version. I prefer to not install any plugin but to use the default jQuery features to achieve this.

$(document).ready(function (){
            $("#click").click(function (){
                $('html, body')
            });
        });
    
    
        Test
    
    
    
        Test 2
    
    Click me

Comment: <input type="text" class="textfield" value="" id="subject" name="subject">

Comment: for button submit

Comment: <input type="submit" class="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Ok, Done.">

Comment: Post all HTML and JQUERY you have tried so far in the question itself not in comments.. Such text is not enough to get accurate help.

Comment: please add the jquery code you tried

Comment: <html>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function (){
            $("#click").click(function (){
                $('html, body')
            });
        });
    </script>
    <div id="div1" style="height: 1000px; width 100px">
        Test
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div id="div2" style="height: 1000px; width 100px">
        Test 2
    </div>
    <button id="click">Click me</button>
</html>

Comment: @GauthamSrinivasan. Check my answer

Comment: ya nair i will check once

Comment: <script>
        $(document).ready(function (){
            $("#click").click(function (){
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $("#div1").offset().top
                }, 2000);
            });
        });
    </script>

Comment: ya super thanks Nair its help full ...

Comment: @GauthamSrinivasan. If its perfect, Please tick that as answer, So that it may be useful to others as well

Comment: ya sure Nair...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this. I have binded to [focus](https://api.jquery.com/focus/) and [click](https://api.jquery.com/click/) events, Update that as per your needs

```js
$("#subject").on('focus click',function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#submit").offset().top
    }, 3500);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="text field" value="" id="subject" name="subject" />
<div class="div">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus 
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus 
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus 
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus 
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus 
     Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus
       Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus
</div>
<input type="submit" class="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Ok, Done."/>
```